# open rest endpoint with spring security

Tags: spring, security, model-view-controller

I am a mobile developer, and a green horn with Spring Security, but any case it was working fine in my web app. But now I am stuck with an issue. 
Lets suppose my app context is x and I want to allow everybody to use a rest service endpoint like

https://localhost:8443/x/12

This endpoint is defined in a Controller in this way:

```
@Secured("permitAll")
@RequestMapping("/{id}")
public ModelAndView foo(@PathVariable("id") int id, HttpServletRequest request) {
    Pet existingPet = petService.getPet(id);

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

    if (null != existingPet) {
        mav.addObject("petAttribute", existingPet);
        mav.setViewName("b-show-pet");
    }else{
        mav.setViewName("b-accessdenied");
    }
    return mav;
}
```

In my web.xml I have

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>loc-app</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/auth/**</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>loc-app</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Enable Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Now, IMO an URI like

https:/localhost:8443/x/15

should be intercepted by spring security, but the annotation @Secured("permitAll") above the service in the controller should be enable access. But it is not working. So, please enlighten me about what is wrong in my code or better, which is best way to do this. Regards,

Comment: @Secured annotation is used for authorization, not for authentication.  With this annotation you check is current user (that already authenticated) have permit to this method, or not. Do you understand that? I ask cus i wanna be sure what i correctly understand which behavior you want to achive.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, to be honest I have no time to read all Spring Security documentation. I want to allow everybody, and I mean people which is not logged, to access my web service. I think permitAll will work in this way. Allowing everybody to access the service.

Answer (score 0):

Secured annotation is used for authorization purposes, for your needs this more suitable (if you wanna use xml config):

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/yoururl" access="permitAll" />
</http>
```

Comment: Ok, yes, Alexander, I know you can use that with a standard URI like /my-bills, but which is the way to allow an uri pattern like /{id}? I mean, without crash with other tags like  <security:intercept-url pattern="/"
   access="isAuthenticated()" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
   access="isAuthenticated()" />

Comment: I have no project for chek at hand, but ant mathers should support regex expressions. Read this: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html

Comment: and be aware, what more specific interceptor should be at the top, bcus spring will check them in announced order, until first coincidence occur.